# Convert AMR file to WAV on C#

Tags: converters, wav, audio-recording, amr

In my android application i want to record an audio file and send to service (ASP service) with smallest size of file.

And I found that .AMR file is one of orginal record files on Android and it has smallest file.

How can I convert .AMR to .WAV on C#.